# Error in apt-get update - how to remove module - The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

When running apt-get update I get the following error (Ubuntu):

```
Hit:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Hit:4 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                                                            
Get:5 http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable InRelease [3,012 B]                                                         
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                             
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Err:5 http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 544B7F63BF9E4D5F
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 544B7F63BF9E4D5F
E: The repository 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've already tried to add the missing public key as per instructions in other posts. That didn't work. Now I want to remove and (maybe) reinstall the offending (Tensorflow?) module. However, I can't figure out how to identify the name of the module to uninstall.

I've tried e.g. "apt list | grep -i tensor" but I can't seem to figure out the name of the module to remove with an "apt-get remove " command.

Anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't exactly figure out how to get rid of the "module" however by running this command:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list && curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

which is described in the tensorflow documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/setup , I at least got rid of the error :o)